# Subtract miliseconds from currentTimeMillis

Tags: coldfusion

Our server is out of sync and 2 minutes ahead from EST

I wanted to subtract 2 minutes from the currentTimeMillis

```
<cfdump var="#getCurrentTimeWithOffset(2)#">

private numeric function getCurrentTimeWithOffset(minutesOffset)
{


    var minutesToMilis = arguments.minutesOffset * 60 * 1000;
    var currentTimeMillis = createObject("java", "java.lang.System").currentTimeMillis();
    var returnTime = currentTimeMillis - minutesToMilis;


    return returnTime;
}
```

How do you subtract miliseconds from currentTimeMillis()?

My current function returns 1.58288854019E+012 which converted the int to exponential format.

Comment: You are doing the subtraction correctly. The 1.58288854019E+012 is just representation, it's not a different value from the one which would be shown as a normal number.

Comment: I don't think you want to get into the business of updating the server's time in your code.  Fix the real problem.  Update the server time on the server.  They should be synchronizing with the same source system.

Comment: @Miguel-F That's true. I've already synched to pool.ntp.org to fix the server time but its still ahead by 2 minutes. I'm exploring other options via code. A bad idea but possible.

Comment: @LajosArpad how can I improve the function to expound 1.58288854019E+012 and display it to non exponential form.

Comment: There may be another issue somewhere. If you're synching time with a single source, it should be the same. That's the whole purpose of ntp servers.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting from your function? I'm not sure it's showing you what you think it is. Your outputting the number of milliseconds since midnight 1970-01-01 minus 120000, which will give you a really long number (thus the scientific notation). Are you looking for a date object?

Comment: @Shawn I want to understand why it transformed the value to exponential form when I'm expecting it in a non exponential form. Then I can transform the expanded form to date object.

Comment: @Vlad Because the object that `currentTimeMillis()` returns is a `long`. So even when you subtract an `int` from it, the `int` is turned into a `long` before it's subtracted, so your end result is still a `long`.  A long can hold an extremely large number. You don't necessarily need do anything to transform it to a date object, because a date is really nothing more than a tic count from a system's Epoch (or 0 time).  That's why actual date math would be a better option. Each time you transform the data, you might slightly modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Large numbers can be output in different ways across CF engines. The value can still be used as you would expect for other purposes. If you would like it to be presented cleanly as an integer you can wrap it in `int()` which results in simplified output for Adobe CF, or have full control with `numberFormat()` and its various options.

Comment: This number is fairly useless, though. It's the scientific notation of the number of milliseconds since Epoch ( 1 Jan 1970 ) at the time the calculation was made with a deduction of a known input. Yes, it _can_ be converted back into a date, but this really seems like it's an X-Y Problem. If the goal is to fix a bad time offset, then my suggestions would be to 1) Fix the problem causing the offset, or 2) Use one of the date functions already built into the language to add the assumed 2 minutes.

Comment: @dan please care to show the answer via code. I'm expecting the returned value to be in the form of 1582947663163 but returned in 1.58294754313E+012 format

Comment: @vlad It's displayed that way because the number is larger than an `int` can be. They can only go up to about 2.15 billion. And the number of milliseconds since Unix Epoch is quite large. An `int` ran out of the ability to display `milliseconds since epoch` before the end of the first month in January 1970. Your number is basically saying that it's been about 1,582,947,543,130 milliseconds since midnight 1/1/1970.

Comment: 1,582,947,543,130  << Your number
       2,147,483,647  << max Int

Comment: TRIVIA TIME: Since a lot of systems still measure `seconds` since Unix Epoch with an `int`, then at about 3:14 on the morning of 19 Jan, 2038 GMT, we're gonna run into some problems. Fortunately, some very smart people heeded the warnings of other very smart people that dealt with a similar issue on 1 Jan 2000.

Comment: @Vlad I would ask again, why do you need to care about this number? Actual date math would be more accurate. And fixing the problem that's causing an offset would be better still.

Comment: @Shawn I want to know if its possible. I think the 2.15 billion is the limitation that's why it transformed into Exponent format. I tried wrapping in int() and that's one of the answer I'm looking. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: @Vlad Yes, it is possible. The thing that you see on the screen isn't necessarily the thing that the computer sees when it's working with it. And since ColdFusion will try to do a lot of type conversion behind the scenes, It sees a number that is much bigger than an integer and outputs it in a format that makes sense to a human.

Comment: There is also a lot of type conversion going on, and they numbers that flow through the process aren't always what they seem to be. 
 https://trycf.com/gist/676ff7477d40ee6d3921bff07ae4b4a5/acf2016?theme=monokai